# Using jq, how can I limit values based on a key

Tags: jq

For an input file that looks like this:

```
{
  "employees": [
    {
      "number": "101",
      "tags": [
        {
          "value": "yes",
          "key": "management"
        },
        {
          "value": "joe",
          "key": "login"
        },
        {
          "value": "joe blogs",
          "key": "name"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "number": "102",
      "tags": [
        {
          "value": "no",
          "key": "management"
        },
        {
          "value": "jane",
          "key": "login"
        },
        {
          "value": "jane doe",
          "key": "name"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "number": "103",
      "tags": [
        {
          "value": "no",
          "key": "management"
        },
        {
          "value": "john",
          "key": "login"
        },
        {
          "value": "john doe",
          "key": "name"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

... I'd like to get details for all non-management employees so that the desired output looks like this:

```
{
  "number": "102",
  "name": "jane doe",
  "login": "jane"
}
{
  "number": "103",
  "name": "john doe",
  "login": "john"
}
```

I can't figure out how to limit results based on a key without selecting that key (in this case "management")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following is a slightly more succinct solution:

```
.employees[]
| .tags |= from_entries
| select(.tags.management == "no")
| {number, "name": .tags.name, "login": .tags.login}
```

Comment: Thanks.  More succinct wins :)

Answer (score 0):

Using `from_entries`, this worked for me:

```
$ jq '.employees[] | {number: .number, tags: .tags | from_entries} | select(.tags.management=="no") | {number: .number, name: .tags.name, login: .tags.login}' input
```

... and the output is:

```
{
  "number": "102",
  "name": "jane blogs",
  "login": "jane"
}
{
  "number": "103",
  "name": "john doe",
  "login": "john"
}
```

There may be a better way to achieve what I wanted, so I'll leave the question open for a while if someone wants to offer a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution which uses [from_entries](https://github.com/stedolan/jq/blob/master/src/builtin.jq#L24)

```
  .employees[]
| {number} + (.tags | from_entries)
| if .management == "no" then {number, name, login} else empty end
```